# How to automate a docker server using python

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu-16.04, dockerpy

I'm a newbie in docker and planning to automate a docker server using python. Hence I need to know how to check whether the docker is up or not, the container is up or not, server disk space utilization and so on. I need some hints to proceed.

Comment: Do you want to check whether docker is running or not using python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env()  # to connect using the default socket or the configuration in your environment

client.containers.list()
```

output:

```
[<Container: ab0744e975>, <Container: 0acce75faa>]
```

the above output is just an example from my pc that shows that docker is running and there are 2 containers

or you can use

```
client.info()
```

from the [docs](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client.html#docker.client.DockerClient.info):

> Display system-wide information. Identical to the docker info command.
>
> Returns:  The info as a dict Return type: (dict)
>
> Raises:   docker.errors.APIError – If the server returns an error.

---

to check if the system is responsive you can use

```
client.ping()
```

Comment: What if   client.containers.list() return null ?

Comment: I need to implement this without the docker library.